# Behat Selenium - Waiting for elements that slide in

Tags: php, selenium, behat, mink

I'm having trouble with Behat waiting for element to "slide in".

In our admin panel menu each primary item slides down to reveal a submenu, as can be seen here:

[image]

I've added redlines to show the menu, and a green one for the submenu just for clarity.

The problem is, this menu "slides" in. It's a lovely effect but it's ruining my tests. :)

I'm trying to use a [spin function](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/using_spin_functions.html) to cause Behat to wait until the submenu is visible before trying to click in it.

**Code:**

```
/**
 * @When I wait for :cssSelector
 * @param $cssSelector
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function iWaitFor($cssSelector)
{
    $this->spin(function($context) use ($cssSelector) {
        /** @var $context FeatureContext */
        return !is_null($context->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', $cssSelector));
    });
}

/**
 * @When I wait for :text to appear
 * @Then I should see :text appear
 * @param $text
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function iWaitForTextToAppear($text)
{
    $this->spin(function($context) use ($text) {
        /** @var $context FeatureContext */
        return $context->getSession()->getPage()->hasContent($text);
    });
}

/**
 * @When I wait for :text to disappear
 * @Then I should see :text disappear
 * @param $text
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function iWaitForTextToDisappear($text)
{
    $this->spin(function($context) use ($text) {
        /** @var $context FeatureContext */
        return !$context->getSession()->getPage()->hasContent($text);
    });
}

/**
 * Based on Behat's own example
 * @see http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/using_spin_functions.html#adding-a-timeout
 * @param $lambda
 * @param int $wait
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function spin($lambda, $wait = 60)
{
    $time = time();
    $stopTime = $time + $wait;
    while (time() < $stopTime)
    {
        try {
            if ($lambda($this)) {
                return;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // do nothing
        }

        usleep(250000);
    }

    throw new \Exception("Spin function timed out after {$wait} seconds");
}
```

And a snippet of the feature:

```yaml
@javascript
Scenario Outline: Create a new piece of artwork
  Given I am logged in to the CMS as "adminUser"
  Then I should see "Artwork"
  When I follow "Artwork"
  Then I should see "Pieces" appear
  When I follow "Pieces"
  Then I should see "Manage Artwork Pieces"
```

However, while this works perfectly fine on my Vagrant development environment, it breaks in Jenkins when it tries to `follow "Pieces"` after it has acknowledge that "Pieces" has appeared. Both are running Selenium with Firefox in XVFB on headless linux.

These are the versions I'm currently using:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ Environment ║ Development  ║ Testing    ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ Linux       ║ Ubuntu 14.04 ║ CentOS 6.6 ║
║ PHP         ║ 5.5.9        ║ 5.4.38     ║
║ Behat       ║ 3.0.x-dev    ║ 3.0.x-dev  ║
║ Selenium    ║ 2.45.0       ║ 2.45.0     ║
║ XVFB        ║ 1.15.1       ║ 1.15.0     ║
║ Firefox     ║ 36.0.4       ║ 31.5.0     ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

I'm going to try making sure Firefox and Selenium are both as up to date as possible to see if that resolves the problem, however this has been an ongoing issue for a while, so I'm not convinced.

**Addendum**

I missed an example of the actual error message:

```
When I follow "Carousel" # tests/Behat/Cms/Features/1.1.Carousel.feature:11
  Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (110, 17): http://www.###.co.uk/admin/fp/carousel
  Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
```

This is directly after `Then I should see "Carousel" appear`

Additionally, the errors occur almost randomly. I need a fool proof way of making sure that the test does not continue until the page is in a state that will allow it to continue. I want avoid anything like a "wait" or anything that is dependent on JavaScript or Selenium specifically (in case I switch to another driver).

**Update:** Updated Selenium on Test machine to 2.45.0, still got the same problem. Corrected PHP version on Dev Environment above, had 5.4, is actually 5.5.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have fixed this, but I'm not 100% sure of the reason, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

I *guess* that checking the page for content will always return true, regardless of whether it's visible or not. Instead, I switched to using the assertions provided by Mink, that are implemented independently for each driver. In this case we're asking Selenium for it's thought on whether the element is present or not.

I had originally avoided the assertions because they throw Exceptions, however, because the exceptions are specific and knowable, we can use this to our advantage.

Here's the new code.

```
/**
 * @When I wait for :text to appear
 * @Then I should see :text appear
 * @param $text
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function iWaitForTextToAppear($text)
{
    $this->spin(function(FeatureContext $context) use ($text) {
        try {
            $context->assertPageContainsText($text);
            return true;
        }
        catch(ResponseTextException $e) {
            // NOOP
        }
        return false;
    });
}

/**
 * @When I wait for :text to disappear
 * @Then I should see :text disappear
 * @param $text
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function iWaitForTextToDisappear($text)
{
    $this->spin(function(FeatureContext $context) use ($text) {
        try {
            $context->assertPageContainsText($text);
        }
        catch(ResponseTextException $e) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

I've since run the test suites twice, with variants of this check occurring about 100 times in each and they've both come back ok. I will leave the question open for now in case anyone wants to submit a better answer / explanation.

Comment: Marked as correct as I've had no further issues with this and no one else has come up with an answer. :)

Comment: Missing the spin() method

Comment: It's in the question.